# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 error when my spigot/bukkit plugin is run on the server

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I made a very simple blank spigot plugin for Minecraft and I exported everything but I got an error when I started the plugin on the server that said: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the message when the code was compiled in Java 8 and then you attempt to run it with an older JDK/JRE.